# How to do circular scroll view?

Tags: iphone

I am doing an application in which i have to show a semi circle on which there should be different options in scroll view. That means on that image of semicircle i have to show scroll in circular way .

How can i do that??

Can anyone please guide me ?

Comment: let me too searching this. let me know if u find result.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you'd need to rotate the contents inside the semi-circle like in a "wheel of fortune" kind of way?
I don't think you can do that with a regular `UIScrollView`, you'd have to handle the touches and do the rotation yourself.
I'd recommend you start by taking a look at the "Touches" code sample from the UIKit docs:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007435